# Custom label on top of the Highchart using swift and highchart cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I have Column chart in which i want to show rank of the chart on top of the column . i tried to show dataLabels but it only shows y value on the top. is that any way to add custom label on the top?

i tried to find answer on Highchart forums and Github forums for the same.please help me out with the code example.

[Current column chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwKA4.png)

i want to show custom value on top of the colomn.

```
let column = HIColumn()
column.data = arySerisModel[i].aryData
```

where 'arydata' is array of float values.

i have another array = [1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7]
which i want to show on middle of column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dataLabels.format` property or the `dataLabels.formatter()` callback function to set custom label text.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: 'Custom label'
        }
    }
},
```

Implementing this in Swift will look like this:

```
let options = HIOptions()
let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
plotOptions.series = HISeries()
let dataLabels = HIDataLabels()
dataLabels.enabled = true
dataLabels.formatter = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { const point = this.point, customLabel = point.customLabel; return `${customLabel ? customLabel : point.y}`; }")
plotOptions.series.dataLabels = [dataLabels]
options.plotOptions = plotOptions
let series = HISeries()
series.data = [
    ["y": 29.9],
    ["y": 71.5, "customLabel": "Custom A"],
    ["y": 129.2, "customLabel": "Custom B"],
    ["y": 144]
]
options.series = [series]
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/afub368p/ 
**Docs**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.format

Comment: is that any swift code for the same?

Comment: and is that possible to add different custom value for different points?

Comment: I updated the answer adding implementations of this in Swift